# how to query a table in a Catalog - schema - table structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a catalog called TEKLABEL, a schema called PUB, a table called MstrShip

when I try to query the table I used

```
from PUB.MstrShip
```

and system gives me error : Invalid Object Name "PUB.MstrShip"

How can I query that table then?

Background: I'm working on a very old windows server 2003 SP2 and SQL server is old too (SQL Query Analyzer Ver. 8.00.2039). When I use the ODBC Query Tool v1.38 to query the tables, I used "PUB.MstrShip" it can execute and give me results. But when I want to run a test program with "PUB.MstrShip" specified in the program, it would report error "Invalid Object Name 'PUB.MstrShip'"

[image]
This is the SQL query analyzer connection string

[image]
This is the program connection string in config file

[image]
This is the structure

Comment: Have you tried a 3-part naming convention such as `SELECT * FROM TEKLABLE.PUB.MstrShip` ?

Comment: No, because this involves a lot of manual changing in the program, that's why I didn't do and hopefully I can be certain before I change...

Comment: What connection string does your program use to connect to the database?

Comment: JamieA is right. If you don't specify the catalog on login, it will take the default catalog, probably Master.

Comment: I just added the connection string

Comment: I have updated my answer, try the the suggestion by tgolisch and change the default db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try amending your connection string to connect to the teklable database, that should only be one manual change in your program. eg

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog=TEKLABLE;UserId=Your_Username;Password=Your_Password;"
```

Looking at your connection properties, I would advise trying the suggestion of tgolisch and change the default database for the sqluser login to be teklable

Which version of SQL Server are you using?  If you connect to the server using SSMS, and go to Security > Logins , then you can edit the properties for the SQLuser login, and change the default database.

It may be worth checking that no other applications use this login, as your change could break them.  A better option could be to create a new login called TEKLABELuser, and set the default database to be teklable

Comment: so how should I change my program config file? or how should I change the code? "from TEKLABEL.PUB.MstrShip"?

Comment: updated answer, can you connect to SQL server with SSMS?

Comment: In ODBC, you can also define/override your default catalog. If there is only one or more machines to touch, this would be reasonable.  However, if there are hundreds, then you should consider setting the default at the SQL Server (security) level.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can specify the default catalog for your login(s) to be TEKLABEL.  Then your queries should work as-is.  Otherwise, you could specify it in your connection strings, as JamieA has shown.